# async/await not waiting for return value in javascript

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I am currently trying out Next.js and Prisma, but had difficulties on getting values from a database. The values are set to `undefined` despite having `await` in it.

My index.js:

```js
import * as Database from "../../../Database";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const username = await Database.getUsername('633d5c12e0bf4ed28b2c3428') //Undefined
    return {        
        props: {
            username: username
        }
    };
}
```

My Database.js

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function getUsername(userid) {
    const query = await prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
            id: userid
        },
        select: {
            username: true,
        }
    })
    return query[0].username; //Debugging confirms query[0].username has the correct value
}
```

I put breakpoint on both when I assign `const username = await...` and `return query[0].username;` and it was seen that it first stop at `const username = await...` and then stopping at `return query[0].username`. I can confirm `Database.getUsername(userid)` is working as indended and returns the correct value but `getServerSideProps()` is not waiting for `Database.getUsername(userid)` before assigning username to undefined

Comment: where is the `return` in `getStaticProps()`?

Comment: When you declare getUsername function there is no Database parameter to use. but when you are running the function you are calling it as Database.getUsername(id). is the method correct? where does Database come from?

Comment: The database and `getUsername(userid)` is run on a seperate database.js file. And I confirm those are correct and `query[0].username` do contain the correctvalue. However since `getUsername()` is an async function my `getStaticProps()` is not waiting on `getUsername()` and gets the value undefined.

Comment: You `await` the query in `getStaticProps`, so that is not the reason why

Comment: Also on a side note, if you're trying to display the unique username of each user in your application, you'll need to use `getServerSideProps`, not `getStaticProps`. Otherwise all of your users will see the same username because `getStaticProps` gets run once at build time.

Comment: if you are calling the function with async/await syntax, how do you know that it doesn't wait? I don't doubt that your getUserName() functions works. Because you say it works elsewhere. So that means you are not using it correctly wherever you are calling it. Maybe you are not creating the correct new Database() method where you are calling these functions.
Apart from all @rantao is right. staticprops run at build time, so all usernames will be same with this current set up. If you want accurate help, maybe you can share more code of these files

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning from the getStaticProps() so NextJS has no idea what props there are

Comment: Yes I have not returned anything yet, however the debugger is shown that username is undefined and I want that resolved first.

Comment: @Muni you will need to post more code then. I'm gonna have to request a working example of your code because your (edited) question works on my side